# How to copy the last field in table1 to the last fields in table2 in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to copy the last project from the project table into the last line of the contact table

```
Table1(project)                          Table2(contact)

Num | name_projet|                         id| name_projet| nom
----------------------                   --------------------------     
1   | projet1                             1  | projet2    | alex
2   | projet2
3   | last_projet3                        10 |            | david

result

id | name_projet | nom
------------------------ 
1  | projet2     | alex
10 | last_projet3| david
```

This is my Query

```
UPDATE CONFIGURATION_VENDUE SET LIBELLE_PROJET =
       (select top 1[a].[libelle_projet] from Projets as a 
               order by Num  desc) ;
```

Comment: So copy the `name_projet` with the highest `num` value from the `project` table to the `name_projet` field in the `contact` table that has the highest `id` value and where the `name_projet` field is Null?

Comment: I just want to copy the last project name into the last line in table 2, I did not quite understand what you told me, i need your help

Comment: That's the problem with databases - the last line isn't necessarily the last item added to the database.  The sort order in a database is irrelevant, so my question was on how to identify the last item you added - I'm assuming it's the record with the highest `num` value in the `project` table.  I'm also assuming the last record in the `contact` table is the one with the highest `id` value and nothing in `name_projet`.

Comment: I already made a request to copy the last row of the project table in all the fields of the table configuration_vendue, so I just want to copy the last name of the project in the last fields of the configuration table

Comment: UPDATE CONFIGURATION_VENDUE,(select top 1 [libelle_projet] from  Projets order by Num desc)  AS x SET CONFIGURATION_VENDUE.LIBELLE_PROJET = x.[libelle_projet];

Comment: You can always query what the last project added to your table is by using the query you have written `select top 1[a].[libelle_projet] from Projets order by Num  desc`. Also you should be storing the Project ID not the name. Why not get the user to select the project ID when they make the entry into the contact table, you could use the last one as a default.